# Nifi convert sql to json structured

Tags: apache-nifi, avro

I am trying to figure out a way to get data out of SQL and format it in a specific json format and i am having a hard time doing that in nifi.

Data that is in the table looks like this.

```
{
    "location_id": "123456",
    "name": "My Organization",
    "address_1": "Address 1",
    "address_2": "Suite 123",
    "city": "My City",
    "state": "FL",
    "zip_code": "33333",
    "description": "",
    "longitude": "-2222.132131321332113",
    "latitude": "111.21321321321321321",
    "type": "data type"
}
```

And i want to convert it into a format like this.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    $.longitude,
                    $.latitude
                ]
            },
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "name": $.name,
                "phone": $.phone_number,
                "address1": $.address_1,
                "address2": $.address_2,
                "city": $.city,
                "state": $.state,
                "zip": $.zip_code,
                "type": $.type
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what i have so far and by all means if i am doing this in a weird way let me know.

[image]

I was thinking i could split all of these into single record jsons format them in this format.

```
{
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    $.longitude,
                    $.latitude
                ]
            },
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "name": $.name,
                "phone": $.phone_number,
                "address1": $.address_1,
                "address2": $.address_2,
                "city": $.city,
                "state": $.state,
                "zip": $.zip_code,
                "type": $.type
            }
        }
```

And then merge all of the records together and merge it back around this

```
{
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
        ]
}
```

I def feel like i am doing this weird, just not sure how to get it done haha.

Comment: check nifi jolt processors to transform json, https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Jolt-quick-reference-for-Nifi-Jolt-Processors/ta-p/244350

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ExecuteSQLRecord with a JsonRecordSetWriter instead of ExecuteSQL, this will allow you to output the rows as JSON objects without converting to/from Avro. If you don't have too many rows (that would cause an out-of-memory error), you can use JoltTransformJSON to do the whole transformation (without splitting the rows) with the following Chain spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "#FeatureCollection": "type",
      "*": {
        "#Feature": "features[&1].type",
        "name": "features[&1].properties.name",
        "address_1": "features[&1].properties.address_1",
        "address_2": "features[&1].properties.address_2",
        "city": "features[&1].properties.city",
        "state": "features[&1].properties.state",
        "zip_code": "features[&1].properties.zip",
        "type": "features[&1].properties.type",
        "longitude": "features[&1].geometry.coordinates.longitude",
        "latitude": "features[&1].geometry.coordinates.latitude"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

If you do have too many rows, you can use SplitJson to split them into smaller chunks, then JoltTransformJSON (with the above spec) then MergeRecord to merge them back into one large array. To get them nested into the `features` field, you could use ReplaceText to "wrap" the array in the outer JSON object, but that too may cause an out-of-memory error.

Comment: this doesnt seem to be working. I am trying to understand how it works to begin with but i just seem to get the hardcoded value back of "type": "FeatureCollection" and nothing else

Comment: What does your input look like? I used the input you provided above and put it (and my spec) into https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ and it came out looking like your desired output.

Comment: Edit...
@mattyb Here is my image https://ibb.co/pLKFzWG

Did this work for you? Or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: My apologies, I assumed since you were trying to Split/Merge that you had an array of the original objects, I wrote the spec based on that assumption. If you put array braces around your original object, the spec will work.

Comment: Oh wow that makes so much more sense now lol. I was fiddling around with that trying to figure out how this worked. It was driving me insane....